# How to fix mongoose "gt" and "lt" not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to get all staff members within a given date range using mongoose ODM, but can't seem to find a way.

I tried using different date formats, but came up with storing ISO date in my db. Now it saves and retrieves dates as `ISODate("2018-12-23T00:00:00Z")` format.

But, what I want is to get all staff members using a date range given using `$gte` and `$lte`

```
/**
 *  Get all attendance of one member for a specific time frame(a month)
 * 
 */
module.exports.getAttendanceTimeFrame = function(params,callback){
    console.log(new Date(params.frm).toISOString());
    AttendanceStaff.find({staff_id: params.staff_id, date:{$gte:params.frm, $lte:params.to}},callback);
}
```

This gives nothing but this gives all staff members who signed that day

```
Model.find({date:'2018-12-22'},callback);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foolish question. Pardon me.. 
I actually found what was wrong with it.. It was a friggin **TYPO**

here is it we can implement this using different approaches
since we store only a date, the mongoose will automatically convert all values we provide to ISODate format (date+time). Its actually very good because a similar pattern for a date or a time. So simply we can use the above code i have given It will work fine

```
   /**
 *  Get all attendance of one member for a specific time frame(a month)
 * 
 */
module.exports.getAttendanceTimeFrame = function(params,callback){
    console.log(new Date(params.frm).toISOString());
    AttendanceStaff.find({staff_id: params.id, date:{$gte:params.frm, $lte:params.to}},callback);
}
```

actually instead of staff_id: **params.staff_id**, all I had to do was **params.id**
because thats how I defined the staff_id in http GET req. which is /staff/**:id**/:frm/:to

anyways we can even use where to do this as well a different approach...

```
/**
 *  Get all attendance of one member for a specific time frame(a month)
 * 
 */
module.exports.getAttendanceTimeFrame = function(params,callback){
    console.log(params.id);
    AttendanceStaff.find({date:{$gte:params.frm, $lte:params.to}}).sort({date:-1}).where({staff_id:params.id}).exec(callback);
}
```

so that's it ...

Answer (score 1):

That's because your params are sending date+time, whereas gte and lte only take date. The output of your log `console.log(new Date(params.frm).toISOString());` should show timestamp